# ruby, how to set ENV variable in each thread?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I'm trying to run a ruby code in parallel using Threads like x2.rb.
I've pasted here a sample code as simple as possible for my problem.
In here, I can't figure out why ENV is not set differently per thread. I've been stuck with this. Can anyone help me out?
Without solving this problem, I can't use Threads at all.

```
# ./x1.rb
test1 a .. a .. {"TEST"=>"a"}
test1 b .. b .. {"TEST"=>"b"}
test1 c .. c .. {"TEST"=>"c"}

# ./x2.rb

test1 a .. a .. {"TEST"=>"c"}       # this needs to be {"TEST"=>"a"}
test1 b .. b .. {"TEST"=>"c"}       # this needs to be {"TEST"=>"b"}
test1 c .. c .. {"TEST"=>"c"}       # this needs to be {"TEST"=>"c"}

x1.rb:

#!/usr/bin/ruby

test_hash = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

def test_env(k, v)
  ENV.clear
  ENV['TEST'] = k.to_s
  print "test1 #{k} .. #{ENV['TEST']} .. "
  p ENV
  # run_cmd(ENV, "cmd to run")
end

test_hash.each do |k, v|
  test_env(k, v)
end

x2.rb:

#!/usr/bin/ruby

test_hash = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
threads = []

def test_env(k, v)
  ENV.clear
  ENV['TEST'] = k.to_s
  print "\ntest1 #{k} .. #{ENV['TEST']} .. "
  p ENV
  # run_cmd(ENV, "cmd to run")
end

test_hash.each do |k, v|
  threads << Thread.new(k, v)  do |k, v|
    test_env(k, v)
  end
end

threads.each(&:join)
```

Comment: Threads are not the same as separate sub-shells or separate invocations of Ruby and a script nor are they in parallel; They share the same interpreter, environment and `ENV`. "Without solving this problem, I can't use Threads at all." Well, that's dramatic. Threads aren't the solution to every problem, but they're very useful, however without an understanding of your goal we can't help much. Perhaps your decision to use threads resulted in an "[XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/153968)" and there might have been a better way to go.

Comment: The reason I chose Threads is I have like 100 DBs in a server. It will take too long to execute a SQL serially. How do u run a code in parallel with a different ENV like ORACLE_SID different for each DB? I chose above simple code to really pinpoint the problem I'm facing now. Any comment is welcome

Comment: @Jon: Probably by using database software/APIs that are intended to be used that way. I know it sounds dismissive, but there is a point beyond which trying to contort software into circumstances it wasn't designed for isn't worth it unless you're doing legacy maintenance.

Comment: Oh boy. I can't wait for you to find out that MRI ruby threads aren't executed in parallel and that they're subject to the global interpreter lock. If you're trying to parallelize a SQL query across an array of instances and you landed on Ruby as the tool to do it, you must be very at odds with engineering.

Comment: @Linuxios, just from above code, ENV can be set per thread? If not, what other options available? Please don't tell me database API. I've been an oracle dba for 20 years. that is not really my question here.

Comment: @coreyward, is it possible to print x2.rb like x1.rb or do you have any other way to do it ?

Comment: @Jon: Even on a Ruby implementation that *isn't* MRI (the one post people use, which doesn't even have real threads), the threads are going to be child processes/threads of the main process, and as such, will share its environment variables on any system I can think of. However, it *is* possible (though I don't remember the details) to spawn another process with different environment variables than your own without changing yours, which I have a feeling is what you actually need to do.

Comment: Here's another idea: instead of insisting on using ENV or arguments, write your configuration data to a file. Load it in the main thread and spawn off workers based on the configuration. Still, you're using a wrench to do open heart surgery.

Comment: Running 100 threads at a time is doable but it doesn't seem like a good solution. Again, without more information we're having to make broad suggestions, but I'd probably write a small app that is used to talk to any DB, depending on the DSN passed to it, and that can accept a query, and returns a result set as JSON, then write code that calls that script. Then you can use sub-shells and their individual ENVs. The calling program would have to wait for the sub shells to finish and would then process the results. The Open3 and JSON classes will be your friends. I'd also look at the Sequel gem.

Answer (score 1):

If you join your threads like this, it will work:

```
test_hash.each do |k, v|
  Thread.new(k, v)  do |k, v|
    test_env(k, v)
  end.join
end
```